# reuse data passed from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I reuse data passed from controller in a view ?

controller's function

```
public function display()
{
   $data=ReadIntoDate();
   $this->load->view('display',$data);
}
```

I would like to use $data in display.php in view. Thank you

Comment: what is $data datatype? you can use its indices as variable in the view file.
If $data['foo'] = 'bar' you can use $foo in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an associative array.

So if you do it like this:

```
public function display()
{
   $data['something'] = ReadIntoDate();
   $this->load->view('display', $data);
}
```

You can call the data in the view like:

```
<h1><?php echo $something; ?></h1>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

$data must be an associative array.

Controllter:

```
$data['blah'] = 'something';
```

view:

```
echo $blah;
```